# How to close a window from an instance of NSObject

Tags: cocoa, user-interface

I started a cocoa project, and it generated AppleDelegate.h, AppleDelegate.m and main.xib files for me. I created some buttons on the window, then create a new class (inherit from NSObject), in the class I do a little thing for button clicks. When one button is clicked, I want the current window to disappear, then a new window to  up. My issue is that I manage to generate a new window when a button is clicked, but I can't figure out how to close the previous window. Do I need to generate my class from NSWindow, instead of NSObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, this maybe useful to someone else.

```
[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] close ];
```

is what I am looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: That would always close the window that happens to be the main window of the application though in most cases you'd want to have more control over **which window in particular** you want to close..